WinForms - Call method in Threading, which calls method in main thread at the end of it
I've seen examples where the thread started in the WinForms class, using Threading.Start(), only calls a helper method defined in that class.
Is it possible to use Threading to first invoke a method defined elsewhere, and then call one defined in the WinForms class itself?
I'd like to have a task running in the background, and only when it completes, a method is called in the WinForms class to update a form element (ex: adds text to a TextBox). So the background task would involve 2 methods, one of which is WinForms related.
When I try this, I get the error about cross-thread operation not valid.

You can use whatever method you want when running a Task (or a Thread), provided that this method knows where to resume when the UI needs to update with the result of this procedure. You usually pass a Progress delegate to this Task, so it doesn't need to know anything about the UI, it just needs to call the Report() method of the IProgress<T> delegate, passing the data that the UI is expecting. T can be anything, a primitive or a structured class that holds any kind of data

How can send that form element modifying/updating method into the background task to run with that other method? When I try, it gives an error about cross-thread operation not valid.

You don't send any reference to UI element. You pass an IProgress<T> delegate that is called back on the UI Thread. Whatever passes the delegate to the Task / Thread, knows what UI elements need to be updated when the method the delegate points to is called

For example, see the use of IProgress delegates to update the UI here: How to download files using HttpClient with a ProgressBar? and here: How can I time the presentation and extraction of frames from a video file?
